# Getting twipsy.js to work (from twitter bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Twitter's Bootstrap css and js modules. Specifically, the twipsy module, which displays a little text message when you hover over a link

there's a demo http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#twipsy

```
blah blha <a href="#" rel="twipsy" data-original-title="Some title text">you probably</a> blah blah   #should display "some title text" when you hover over 'you probably'
```

I copied some of the html from the demo and included twipsy.js in this jsfiddle.net

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/quH9Q/

but when I hover over the link, the text isn't popping up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Include jQuery to use twispy. All Bootstrap JavaScript plugin need jQuery or Ender to work.
2. Activate twispy for selected elements by calling `.twipsy()`. Example you copied from the bootstrap page uses `$("a[rel=twipsy")` .
3. By default the popover is placed above the text. It won't be visible if your text is on top of the page (as in the fiddle). You can configure `placement` option or move the text down.

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/quH9Q/2/)** is the code.

**HTML:**

```
blah blha <a href="#" rel="twipsy" data-original-title="Some title text">you probably</a> blah blah
```

**JS:**

```
$("a[rel=twipsy]").twipsy({ placement: "below" });
```